# Как с помощью виджета обращаться сетевым компонентам?

Tags: android, java

Есть код для отключения и включения Wi-Fi адаптера:

```
String service = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
        wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(service);

    public void Connected(){

            if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
                if (wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING)                 
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

            }
```

Но как это реализовать в виджете?

Comment: почитай про виджеты, в чем проблема?

Comment: Ну например, тут используется метод getSystemService, который реализованный в классе Activity.

Comment: @Александр Денисенко: вы, наверное, хотите сделать всё в обработчике `OnClick`? Делайте сразу правильно, проблем не будет. Отошлите событие модели, она пусть общается с `Activity`.